# How to fix string request/get function

Tags: php

I am trying to pull url string items (utm fields), combine them into one variable (vtid) and pass to page but it is only passing dashes, the url info is not passing.

```
<?

$utm_source   = $_REQUEST['utm_source'];
$utm_medium   = $_REQUEST['utm_medium'];
$utm_campaign = $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'];
$utm_term     = $_REQUEST['utm_term'];
$utm_content  = $_REQUEST['utm_content'];

$vtid = $utm_source . "-" . $utm_medium . "-" . $utm_campaign . "-" . $utm_term . "-" . $utm_content;

?>
```

`print_r($_REQUEST);` shows

```
Array ( 
    [gr_subscriber] => exists 
    [email] => myemail@me.com 
    [http_referer] => example.com=&utm_source=as&utm_medium=ms&utm_campai… 
    [webforms_id] => 657433 
    [name] => Friend 
)
```

Comment: echo out the variables that are not showing up and see if you are even getting the info before combining them.

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST);` And show us the output

Comment: echoing out variables except first returns no value for first...

Comment: This is what happens when developing with php "display_errors" set to false! try to print the $_REQUEST as @RiggsFolly recommended

Comment: thanks... so the output is Array ( [gr_subscriber] => exists [email] => myemail@me.com [http_referer] => https://www.example.com=&utm_source=as&utm_medium=ms&utm_campaign=cs&utm_term=ts&utm_content=cs [webforms_id] => 657433 [name] => Friend )

Comment: It seems the utm values are stuck in the http referrer

Comment: so I tried this but same result... <?

list($hr,$utm_source,$utm_medium,$utm_campaign,$utm_term,$utm_content) = explode(“&”,$_REQUEST[‘http_referer]);
$vtid = $utm_source . "-" . $utm_medium . "-" . $utm_campaign . "-" . $utm_term . "-" . $utm_content;

?>

Comment: @plm `print_r` the result of `explode(“&”,$_REQUEST[‘http_referer']);`

Comment: Array ( [gr_subscriber] => exists [email] => myemail@me.com [http_referer] => example.com?pid=5&utm_source=as&utm_medium=ms&utm_campaign=cs&utm_term=ts&utm_content=cs [webforms_id] => 23842401 [name] => Friend )

Comment: I solved this on my own!